# Connect to Wifi and Ethernet use the Ethernet for services hosted and wifi for regular internet

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet

I have two routers one is secured with VPN the other is not. 
I have a Raspberry Pi 4
I am running Vanilla Raspbian

I would like internet traffic to run through the VPN secured router using WIFI 
then 
I would like to host my Homebridge server and other servers via ethernet on the none secured network for local usage.

I can setup static IPs but I can't seem to figure out to to say use this internet connection.

How do you route traffic for each application?

Edit:------Adding clarity

I have a mail server and a homebridge server on the Pi. I would like the mail server to run on the wifi and Hombridge to run on the ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to set the interface that goes to your internet connection as the default route (or route of last resort),  and enable ip forwarding on the your pi/rspian/linux. The other interface would be the gateway to a subnet where all the other stuff lives.

use /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1  to enable it temporary or:

add net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

to /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf
(that's how it works on rhel/centos, raspian is probably very similar if also systemd).

and then /sbin/sysctl -p    or reboot

(that is how it works in rhel/centos, or any systemd linux)

Comment: If I’m understanding you this switches between the networks for all apps is that right?

Comment: well,  if your clients can all reach the multi-homed  server, yes.  for example.  you would setup 3 virtual servers/interfaces.  lets say  192.168.1.37, 38 and 39  that way you'd have your 3 "front ends".  the multihomed server then  takes care of the incoming traffic itself,  or redirects it to where it needs to be.  from the "outside" you would just see 3 hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Make the VPN router your default gateway (perhaps it already is), and then configure the the services to listen only on the right IP address instead of `0.0.0.0`. Assuming your WiFi adapter gets assigned `192.168.1.5` and Ethernet gets `192.168.2.10`, you need your mail server to listen on `192.168.1.5` and the homebridge (whatever that is) to listen on `192.168.2.10`. Check out the documentation of both servers to figure out how to do it, typically there are configuration parameters called `Listen`, `Bind`, `ListenAddress`, `BindAddress` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is imprecise and lacking detail.

To answer the first part of your Question you can setup *Raspberry Pi OS* to use WiFi for default routing.

Firstly setup your network, without Ethernet connected, **THEN** add

```
interface eth0
nogateway
```

to the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

See **Prevent dhcpcd from configuring a gateway on an interface** in 
[How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

There is insufficient information to explain how to setup EtherNet as it is unclear what you are trying to achieve; you may want to use a static IP address, setup as an Access Point and/or install a DHCP server for the Ethernet interface.

When you have finished you should run `ip r` to show routing.
There should only be a single default for the WiFi interface.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity I have update the question and added: 
I have a mail server and a homebridge server on the Pi. I would like the mail server to run on the wifi and Hombridge to run on the ethernet.